# NSArray and tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm making a navigation-based application, where i have a file called DataService.m and my RootViewController

.m

in my DataService.m I'm calling

```
-(NSArray*)loadData
{
    AlarmItem *item1 = [[[AlarmItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"TEST2"] autorelease];
    AlarmItem *item2 = [[[AlarmItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"TEST3"] autorelease];
    AlarmItem *item3 = [[[AlarmItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"TEST4"] autorelease];
    AlarmItem *item4 = [[[AlarmItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"TEST5"] autorelease];
    AlarmItem *item5 = [[[AlarmItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"TEST6"] autorelease];

    NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, NULL];

    return items;
}
```

and in my RootViewCoontroller.m i have

```
- (IBAction)RefreshAlarmList:(id)sender
{
    XMLDataService *myXML = [[XMLDataService alloc] init];
    [myXML loadData];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem *refreshButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh
    target:self action:@selector(RefreshAlarmList:)]; 
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = refreshButton;
    [refreshButton release];
}
```

When I run my simulator the tableView is empty.. how can i display my items ?

Comment: There are lot of tutorials on table view go through that and then come up with the issues.

Comment: i have tried many turtorials but i cant find an answer.

Comment: Where do you tell your tableview what to load (i.e. rowsPerSection, tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:) ?  and which tutorials have you followed that didn't help?

Answer (score 0):

Dont `autorelease` the function after it load to the tableview then autorelease it.Then how u are displaying the data to the tableview.give action as reload data in tableview.

Comment: should i just release item1 and so on in the dealloc ?

Comment: i have tried to do that but it still dosent show anything in the table

Comment: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    
  // Configure the cell.
  AlarmItem *item = [_items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  cell.textLabel.text = item.tagName;

Answer (score 0):

You can try one thing.Here in the delegate method cellForRowAtIndexPath , in last u should return the cell.It may work.

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell"; UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; if (cell == nil) { cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease]; } // Configure the cell. AlarmItem *item = [_items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; cell.textLabel.text = item.tagName;return cell;}

Answer (score 0):

```
[myXML loadData];
```

This is returning an array, which presumably you wish to use as your table's data source, but you are doing nothing with it. You need to assign this to an array, which is a retained ivar in your view controller class, `_items` or `items` judging by your other comments:

```
self.items = [myXML loadData];
```